# Как сделать многоуровневое меню телеграм бота ( inline — callback) на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть код телеграм бота, который выводит 4 кнопки и при нажатии на каждую из них выводится сообщение.

```
from telebot import types

import constants, os, re

bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def inline(message):
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="NumberOne", 
    callback_data="NumberOne")
    but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="NumberTwo", 
    callback_data="NumberTwo")
    but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="NumberTree", 
    callback_data="NumberTree")
    but_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Number4", 
    callback_data="Number4")
    key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3, but_4)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ВЫБЕРИТЕ КНОПКУ", reply_markup=key)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def inlin(c):
    if c.data == 'NumberOne':
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Это кнопка 1')
    if c.data == 'NumberTwo':
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Это кнопка 2')
    if c.data == 'NumberTree':
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Это кнопка 3')
    if c.data == 'Number4':
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Это кнопка 4')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Как сделать, что бы при нажатии на кнопку - открывалось новое меню из нескольких кнопок, с возможностью вернутся к главному меню?

Comment: Тоже интересует такое меню!! если решение есть поделись кодом, буду признателен

Answer (score 1):

```
#Например, при помощи reply_markup в  edit_message_text


def inline_key(num):
    """Функция для вывода кнопок
    """
    i=1
    btns = []
    while i<=num:
        btns.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка '+str(i+10), callback_data='butt'+str(i+10)))
        i=i+1
    btns.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='назад', callback_data='nazad'))
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(*btns)
    return keyboard 

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
#главное меню
def start(m):
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='кнопка1', callback_data="butt1"))
    key.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='кнопка2', callback_data="butt2"))  
    msg=bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Нажми кнопку', reply_markup=inline_main())
    logging.info(m.chat.id)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def inline(c):

    if c.data=='butt1':
        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=c.message.chat.id,
            message_id=c.message.message_id,
            text="нажата *кнопка 1*",
            parse_mode="markdown")
    elif c.data=='butt2':
        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=c.message.chat.id,
            message_id=c.message.message_id,
            text="нажата *кнопка 2*",
            parse_mode="markdown",
            reply_markup=inline_key(5))
    elif c.data=='nazad':
        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=c.message.chat.id,
            message_id=c.message.message_id,
            text="нажата *кнопка 2*",
            parse_mode="markdown",
            reply_markup=inline_key(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types

token=<token>

bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def inline_key(a):
    if a.text == "Inline_menu":
        mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка 1', callback_data='key1')
        key2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка 2', callback_data='key2')
        mainmenu.add(key1, key2)
        bot.send_message(a.chat.id, 'Это главное меню!', reply_markup=mainmenu)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "mainmenu":
        mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка 1', callback_data='key1')
        key2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка 2', callback_data='key2')
        mainmenu.add(key1, key2)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=mainmenu)
    elif call.data == "key1":
        next_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка 3', callback_data='key3')
        back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='mainmenu')
        next_menu.add(key3, back)
        bot.edit_message_text('Это меню уровня 2, для кнопки1!', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=next_menu)
    elif call.data == "key2":
        next_menu2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка 4', callback_data='key4')
        back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='mainmenu')
        next_menu2.add(key4, back)
        bot.edit_message_text('Это меню уровня 2, для кнопки2!', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=next_menu2)

bot.polling()
```

[Результат](https://drive.google.com/open?id=198yOfWBjNyoBkYAqGFdHxoqm3xlZMRxD)